# D3.js - How to do perform two functions when clicking a button?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am struggling to get a button to do two things on click:

1) move my bubble chart using .force

2) render some text visible on click

At the moment it will use .force on the circles, yet disregard the text part

```
    d3.select("#buttonid").on('click', function(d){
        simulation
            .force('x', d(forceXCombine))
            .alphaTarget(d(0.5))
            .restart(d)
        .select("#text_id_1").transition(d).duration(200).attr("visibility", 'visible')
        .select("#text_id_2").transition(d).duration(200).attr("visibility", 'visible') })
```

Here is the text svgs:

```
            svg.append("text")
                .attr("id",'text_id_1')
                .attr('fill', 'black')
                .attr('stroke','none')
                .attr("x", 40)
                .attr("y", 25)
                .attr('visibility','hidden')
                .attr("font-family", "Arial")
                .attr("font-size", 23)
                .text("text")

            svg.append("text")
                .attr("id",'text_id_2')
                .attr('fill', 'black')
                .attr('stroke','none')
                .attr('visibility','hidden')
                .attr("x", 540)
                .attr("y", 25)
                .attr("font-family", "Arial")
                .attr("font-size", 23)
                .text("some text")
```

and the button id just in case

```
<button id="buttonid">text</button>
```

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: can't you just put both scripts into the same function?

Comment: It was my understanding I was, to be honest.

Comment: Could you show me how I could do this?

Comment: I'm assuming the lines starting with `.select` are the text you are wanting to make visible, and those are running off of the `simulation` variable when, according to what I see in the docs, they should be running off of the `d` variable, so changing `.select` to `d.select` might fix the issue.

Comment: did that fix the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the lines that start with `.select` are what you're referencing with "render some text visible on click".

The `.select` functions are running off of the `simulation` variable when, according to what I see in the docs, they should be running off of the `d` variable that you defined in the callback function, so changing `.select` to `d.select` should fix your issue.